# How to control / limit the frequency of execution of a aws lambda function, within a time interval?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Has someone implemented a lambda that is triggered from an event that is executed 4 or 5 times in an hour and that no longer executes, until another event activates it again.

The main idea is to avoid the lambda execution indefinitely while the original event that triggered it, is present.

thanks a lot!

Comment: *"while the original event that triggered it is present"* seems like it should not be a problem that you have to solve.  What kind of "event" are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer. The lambda function is activated by a CloudWatch event. After that, this lambda activates another lambda that monitors some DeviceFarm logs (aws.amazon.com/en/device-farm). What I need is for the 2nd lambda to run 5 times in an hour, and stop (but I can not disable it, I just need it to stop after 5 executions in an hour). We can call it a process. In the future (some minutes, hours, etc. afterwards) that process can be repeated again. That is to say; a new event CloudWtch can trigger the 1st lambda, and it can trigger the 2nd lambda, and so on ...

Comment: You appear to have created a very complex architecture. There is possibly a much simpler way to achieve your end-goals (eg using queues). Feel free to edit your question to provide details of the end-goal you are trying to achieve (as opposed to _how_ you think you will solve it).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for your answer. Yes, we have also evaluated other alternatives as you mentioned, such as, aws SQS. We're working on that, but the original idea with this question was to ask the community about some ideas / approach to implement it. From your answer I can figure out the SQS could be one alternative. Anyway, we will offer more details of the end-goal.

Comment: Hi, this question has already been solved. We used AWS step functions. Thanks all for your help !